# using normal_distribution in a loop

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if there could be a problem with putting `normal_distribution` in a loop.

Here is the code that uses `normal_distribution` in this strange way:

```
std::default_random_engine generator;
//std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(5.0,2.0);

for (int i=0; i<nrolls; ++i) {
    std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(5.0,2.0);
    float x = distribution(generator);

}
```

Comment: The distribution has internal state, by putting it in the loop you are resetting it. I don't know if the result would be wrong, but it may differ. [Related recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55777705/583833)

Comment: Why not move the initialization outside of the loop? Here "strange" probably means "inefficient and wrong".

Comment: I'm reading someone else's code which did in this strange way. The distribution is still a Gaussian of the random number is still a gaussian with correct mean and width. I'm just wondering if there could be an potential issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the `normal_distribution` object outside the loop may be slightly more efficient than putting it in the loop. When it's inside the loop, the `normal_distribution` object may be re-constructed every time, whereas if it's outside the loop it's only constructed once.

### Comparison of the assembly.

Based on an analysis of the assembly, **declaring `distribution` outside the loop is more efficient.**

Let's look at two different functions, along with the corresponding assembly. One of them declares `distribution` inside the loop, and the other one declares it outside the loop. To simplify the analysis, they're declared const in both cases, so we (and the compiler) know that the distribution doesn't get modified.

You can see [the complete assembly here.](https://godbolt.org/z/j9V_wo)

```
// This function is here to prevent the compiler from optimizing out the
// loop entirely
void doSomething(std::normal_distribution<double> const& d) noexcept;

void inside_loop(double mean, double sd, int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        const std::normal_distribution<double> d(mean, sd); 
        doSomething(d); 
    }
}
void outside_loop(double mean, double sd, int n) {
    const std::normal_distribution<double> d(mean, sd);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        doSomething(d); 
    }
}
```

#### `inside_loop` assembly

The assembly for the loop looks like this (compiled with gcc 8.3 at O3 optimization).

```
.L3:
        movapd  xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [rsp]
        lea     rdi, [rsp+16]
        add     ebx, 1
        mov     BYTE PTR [rsp+40], 0
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp+16], xmm2
        call    foo(std::normal_distribution<double> const&)
        cmp     ebp, ebx
        jne     .L3
```

Basically, it 
- constructs the distribution
- invokes `foo` with the distribution
- tests to see if it should exit the loop

#### `outside_loop` assembly

Using the same compilation options, `outside_loop` just calls `foo` repeatedly without re-constructing the distribution. There's fewer instructions, and everything stays within the registers (so no need to access the stack).

```
.L12:
        mov     rdi, rsp
        add     ebx, 1
        call    foo(std::normal_distribution<double> const&)
        cmp     ebp, ebx
        jne     .L12
```

### Are there ever any reasons to declare variables inside a loop?

**Yes.** There are definitely good times to declare variables inside a loop. If you were modifying `distribution` somehow inside the loop, then it would make sense to reset it every time just by constructing it again.

Furthermore, if you don't ever use a variable outside of a loop, it makes sense to declare it inside the loop just for the purposes of readability.

Types that fit inside a CPU's registers (so floats, ints, doubles, and small user-defined types) oftentimes have no overhead associated with their construction, and declaring them inside a loop can actually lead to *better assembly* by simplifying compiler analysis of register allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [interface](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution) of the normal distribution, there is a member called `reset`, who:

> resets the internal state of the distribution

This implies that the distribution *may* have an internal state. If it does, then you definitely reset that when you recreate the object at each iteration. Not using it as intended *may* produce a distribution which is not normal or might be just inefficient.

What state could it be? That is certainly implementation defined. Looking at one implementation from LLVM, the normal distribution is defined around [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/include/random#L4219-L4342). More specifically, the `operator()` is [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/include/random#L4312-L4341). Looking at the code, there is certainly some state shared in between subsequent calls. More specifically, at each subsequent call, the state of the boolean variable `_V_hot_` is flipped. If it is true, significantly less computations are performed and the value of the stored `_V_` is used. If it is false, then `_V_` is computed from scratch.

I did not look very deep into why did they choose to do this. But, looking only at the computations performed, it should be much faster to rely on the internal state. While this is only some implementation, it shows that the standard allows the usage of internal state, and in some case it is beneficial.

Later edit:

The GCC libstdc++ implementation of `std::normal_distribution` can be found [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/random.h#L1963-L2163). Note that the `operator()` calls another function, `__generate_impl`, which is defined in a separate file [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/random.tcc#L1822-L1880). While different, this implementation has the same flag, here named `_M_saved_available` that speeds up every other call.

Comment: Which compilers or standard library implementations is this true for?

Comment: The implementation I referenced above is the LLVM libcxx: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project, used in clang.

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez I have looked into gcc as well. The libstdc++ provided has a very similar implementation, with a similar behavior. I have updated my answer if you want to have a look.